# Can Excel give a notification if a the value of a cell changes out of limits in a certain time?

Tags: excel, time, intervals

I would like to learn if Excel can notify me if the value of a cell is changed out of a limit within a certain interval?

Example:
Cell A1 has a value of 10, the limits are +1 and -1, the interval is 1 minute
Now I would like to be notified if the value of A1 changes below 9 or above 11 within the interval of 1 minute

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Thank you in advance!
Christiaan

Comment: I'm not understanding when the interval is applied.  How do we know what the baseline is for the 1-minute interval?  If the value changes after the 1-minute interval, does it matter at all?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change event on the worksheet where your cell is, which gets triggered when a cell changes.  I don't know why but when the event gets triggered on my excel 2003 install the Target range is nothing, but either way you can check your cell(s) any time a cell changes, and keep the previous value(s) in a global variable, and the time of the last time each of your watched cells changed.  Knowing the cell's last change time and its last value should be enough information for you to do what you need...